# Is it possible to make a textbox look and act like a textarea through CSS alone?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to get a textbox ("input" with "type=text") to act like a textarea through CSS alone?

I can set the height and width, obviously, but I can't get it to wrap like a text area nor vertically align the contents like one.

I have a situation where I can't change the HTML of the page, but I *can* alter the CSS.  My users want textareas where they just have textboxes, and I'm hoping I can pull it off with CSS alone.

I've tried about every combination of "white-space" and "vertical-align."

Comment: Deane, couldn't you make all your boxes textareas to start with then limit their size for the fields where the extra size isn't required?

Comment: if you can change JavaScript file, simply remove the textbox from form and append a new textarea with the same name and it should work as expected, otherwise there is no way to achieve this with CSS.

Comment: ...is it too late to request that people stop calling text-`input`s 'textboxes'..? :( Also, as @Fatih suggests, is it possible to use JavaScript?

Comment: can you please mark an answer or post your own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  You would need some JavaScript as well to change the browser functions.  For instance when you hit the enter key in a textbox it submits the form, where as in a text area it will add a new line.

Things like that can't be controlled by CSS to my knowledge.